# Why am I getting 415 error when sending a json request and consuming a json in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am sending a JSON post request from postman in below format `{"name":"ABC","id":1}`

and trying to map it with my `Employee` class in Controller with `@Requestbody` 
but still getting error as **HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type** with Headers ( Content-Type : application/json )

1) Controller :

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationController {

        @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping(path="/jsonreq", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String json(@RequestBody Employee e)  
    {
        System.out.println("JSON_2::");

        return "Testing";
    }

}
```

2) Employee Class:

```
public class Employee {

    private int id;
    private String name;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: you have jackson on your classpaht?

Comment: How do you post the data?? You should select raw, specify the type as JSON(application/json)

Comment: @Eric : Yes, raw data as JSON(application/json).

Comment: start app in debug mode put break point in controller method & let us know if control reaches to line - ` return "Testing";` or not.

Comment: Either change `@Controller` to `@RestController` or add the `@ResponseBody` annotation. Currently, Spring does not know what to do with the return value of type *String*.